# Angular: theme switcher

Tags: css, angular

We have done theme switching in the past. In `Angular 1.5` we had 3 css files. The main layout file and 2 color css files. When user selected a theme we would apply the proper color css file to change the theme.

Now in `Angular 2+` we are using sass and each component has its own styles. We cannot use the same approach of having a 'color' css file for each theme.

What is the approach in `Angular 2+` for switching themes when each component has its own css file. I assume there is a way to tell each component to switch to a theme color selector? Any guidance is appreciated, thank-you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to do Sass mixins based on the current theme. Look at how [material](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) theming works.

At the root of your project, you can have a theming.scss file which uses mixins to set up different themes based on a class. You can then easily change the theme by changing the class.